# changing details of class using textfields in java

Tags: java

I need help with changing the value of an attribute of a class using textfields in java Below I have 3 simplified versions of codes to demonstrate the problem I am having. I have 3 classes below the alpha,UIalpha and mainGUI class. When I run the mainGUI class I need a user to click the pc image on the window. this creates the UIaplha object opening a new frame.This frame has a textfield which should be able to change the name attribute of the aplha class object in the mainGUI class. MY code works up to a certain point where I dont know how to fix it. I have searched multiple times and tried many kinds of thing but none have worked for me. [pc image needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9r1O.png)

**Alpha.java**

```
public class alpha{
String name;
public void setName(String n){
  name=n;
  }
  public void print(){
    System.out.println("name= "+name);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    alpha a=new alpha();
  }
}
```

**mainGUI.java**

```
import java.awt.*; // this is used to access the GridLayout class
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
public class mainGUI extends JComponent{
 private static final int WIDTH = 400;
 private static final int HEIGHT = 300;
 private int PCHeight=40;
 private int PCWidth=41;
 int y=20,x=30;
 private JButton pc1button;
 private PCButtonHandler pcbHandler;
 public mainGUI(){
   JFrame frame=new JFrame("NETWORK EXAMPLE");
   ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("pc.png");
   pc1button =new JButton(image);
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   pc1button.setOpaque(false);
   pc1button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
   pc1button.setBorderPainted(false);
   pc1button.setBounds(y,x,PCHeight,PCWidth);
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   pcbHandler=new PCButtonHandler();
   pc1button.addActionListener(pcbHandler);
   frame.setTitle("GUI example");
   Container pane= frame.getContentPane();
   pane.setLayout(null);
   pane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   pane.add(pc1button);
   frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }
 public class PCButtonHandler implements ActionListener
 {
   String name;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      alpha test=new alpha();
      test.setName("WRONG");
      test.print();
      UIalpha help=new UIalpha(test);
      test=help.updateObjects();
      test.print();
    }
  }
 public static void main(String[] args){
   mainGUI work=new mainGUI();
 }
}
```

**UIalpha.java**

```
import java.awt.*; // this is used to access the GridLayout class
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
public class UIalpha extends JFrame{
  String Name;
  private JLabel nameL;
  private JTextField nameTF;
  boolean pressed=false;
  private JButton enterbutton=new JButton("Enter");
  private JFrame frame=new JFrame("PC");
  alpha refrence;
  public UIalpha(alpha test){
    this.refrence=test;
   nameL= new JLabel("Enter the name of alpha: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
   nameTF=new JTextField(10);
   nameTF.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500,20));
   enterbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       refrence.setName(nameTF.getText());
    //   test.setName(nameTF.getText());
       //test.print();
       pressed=true;
     }
   });
   Container pane= frame.getContentPane();
   frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
   pane.add(nameL);
   pane.add(nameTF);
   pane.add(enterbutton);
   frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,200));
   frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,200));
   frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(660,200));
   frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  public alpha updateObjects(){

   return refrence;
  }
}
```

Comment: `MY code works up to a certain point where I dont know how to fix it` That's not very specific. What actually works, and what doesn't?

Comment: so when I press the enter button it changes the passed in aplha object. but the change isn't reflected back to the alpha object in the mainGUI class. What im trying to acheive is to allow the user to press the enter button and then i can use the update object later on in the mainGUI class after the press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, in fact, mostly works. Bah, the change in alpha IS reflected in mainGUI. It's just that you try to print it too early - creating a new frame is not blocking. Both `prints` in `PCButtonHandler` happen immediately, before you had a chance to enter a new value. If you, say, add a new button in mainGUI to print current value of alpha you will be able to see it changed.

Also, since I'm here:

- Java class names should start with a capital letter.
- In order not to get insane when your application grows, use a layout manager (like MigLayout for example).

-edit-

A good moment to try and do something with the new value (for example, update the whole mainGUI wherever needed) would be when the window is closed. You can do it like that in mainGUI right below creating UIalpha:

```
help.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("window closing");
                    test.print();
                }
            });
```

Or well, that SHOULD work, when you fix how you did UIalpha:

- remove `frame` variable
- wherever you call method on that variable call it on UIalpha instead (current object)

because otherwise you'd be setting that listener on a different frame than the one you use.

Comment: Is there any other way apart from a button to see that the change is reflected. How can I wait until the enter button is pressed. I tried something like while(enterpressed==false); but that gave me no textfeilds or button. I also attempted to use a thread, but I don't understand how to use them as I have only done basic java before attempting this kind of thing.

Comment: @DillonWaters expanded the answer

Comment: @DillonWaters fell free to accept the answer if it fixed your problem